# Why does Foo({}) invoke Foo(0) instead of Foo()?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, list-initialization, value-initialization

Executables produced by clang 3.5.0 and gcc 4.9.1 from the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
   Foo() { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
   Foo(int x) { std::cout << "Foo(int = " << x << ")" << std::endl; }
   Foo(int x, int y) { std::cout << "Foo(int = " << x << ", int = " << y << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()                 // Output
{                          // ---------------------
   auto a = Foo();         // Foo()
   auto b = Foo(1);        // Foo(int = 1)
   auto c = Foo(2, 3);     // Foo(int = 2, int = 3)
   auto d = Foo{};         // Foo()
   auto e = Foo{1};        // Foo(int = 1)
   auto f = Foo{2, 3};     // Foo(int = 2, int = 3)
   auto g = Foo({});       // Foo(int = 0)          <<< Why?
   auto h = Foo({1});      // Foo(int = 1)
   auto i = Foo({2, 3});   // Foo(int = 2, int = 3)
}
```

behave as commented.

From [cppreference: cpp/language/list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/list_initialization&oldid=72490):

> ```
> [...]
>
> T( { arg1, arg2, ... } )    (7)
>
> [...]
> ```
>
> The effects of list initialization of an object of type T are:
>
> If `T` is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.
>
> Otherwise, If the braced-init-list is empty and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```

I concluded that `Foo({})` should call the default constructor.

Where's the bug?

Comment: The bug is in cppreference.

Comment: Fixed cppreference to read "The effects of list initialization of an object of type `T` from a *non-parenthesized braced-init-list* are..."  would that have been clearer?

Comment: @Casey I would say no. And would say that `T({...})` is *not* a list initialization of an object of type `T`, rather than to add vague wording that could be misinterpreted. Cpprefrerence already doesn't claim it to be. But with your proposed fix, it would read that `T({...})` is a list initialization of an object of type `T` from a parenthesized braced init list, which is *not* the case. It is a list initialization of whatever parameter the chosen constructor has.

Comment: @Casey alternatively it might be worth to show multiple initializer lists, `T({...}, {...}, ...)` (aswell as in the function case and whereever multiple lists make sense. just as done with `arg1, arg2 ...`). Then it can't be confused as a list initialization of an object of type `T` so easily anymore, I think.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Quite the contrary, Cppreference *did* in fact claim that `T({args...})` is list-initialization. It was listed (pun intended) on [the "list-initialization" page as alternative 7 of the situations in which list-initialization is performed](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/list_initialization&oldid=72490). I think the OP's reading of the page was accurate. The *proper* fix may be to remove items 5, 6, and 7 from the page altogether.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb [Is this better](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=cpp/language/list_initialization&oldid=73604)? The other syntaxes are discussed on the [Overload Resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) page. It would seem that whoever made the list initialization page in the first place was enumerating all cases where a braced-init-list can appear in the grammar, regardless of whether those cases actually involve list-initialization.

Comment: @Casey hm, it certainly *is* list initialization, and it still (IMO) correctly lists it as such. But not list initialization of an object of type `T`. And indeed the page does not claim that it is. Just as it doesn't claim that alternative 5 initializes a function (perhaps more obvious here).

Comment: Perhaps it might be a good idea to replace `T({...})` by `U({...})` to avoid the problem with the text referring to `T`, which here is not right.

Comment: @Casey BTW I just added a comment on the overload resolution page.

Comment: @Casey and litb, I restored and rearranged the [list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) bullet points and made the wording more specific about what's getting initialized where.

Comment: @Cubbi, JohannesSchaub-litb, and Casey Thank you all for clarifying the wording at cppreference.com. Now, referring to "U's constructor's parameter" in case (4) does not seem to be precise since Foo({}) will invoke the default constructor if Foo(int) is removed from the example above.

Comment: @cubbi much better. But case 4 is a function call to a constructor, and *copy* list initializes the parameter. What is direct initialized is the U object by non list initialization.

Comment: @precarious it still is precise. if the int constructor is removed, you are going to call the copy/move constructor.

Comment: @litb right, moved (4) into copy-list-init block.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What about precision with respect to more than one argument? It seems as if `Foo({2, 3})` invokes `Foo(int, int)`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I see it now, nevermind. :-)

Comment: @Cubbi That's much better - thanks for this fix and for all the effort you put into cppreference.

Comment: @Casey btw it would've helped if a link to this SO post accompanied the first edits. It wasn't clear where the confusion originated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default constructor is only applicable if you use one single pair of either braces:

```
auto a = Foo();         // Foo()
auto b = Foo{};         // Foo()
```

`Foo({})` instead will only call constructors with the empty list as the argument, copy-list-initializing the parameter of whatever constructor is chosen. [dcl.init]/16:

> If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type: 
> — If
>   the initialization is direct-initialization […] constructors are considered. The applicable constructors
>   are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one is chosen through overload
>   resolution (13.3). **The constructor so selected is called to
>   initialize the object, with the initializer expression or
>   *expression-list* as its argument(s).** If no constructor applies, or
>   the overload resolution is ambiguous, the initialization is
>   ill-formed.

You have one argument: The empty braced-init-list. There is a list-initialization sequence converting `{}` to `int` so the constructor `Foo(int)` is chosen by overload resolution. The parameter is initialized to zero as `{}` implies a [value-intialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) which, for scalars, implies a [zero-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

There is no bug in cppreferences documentation either: For (7) it is stated that

> 7) in a functional cast expression or other direct-initialization,
>   with braced-init-list used as the constructor argument

Which clearly leads to the same result as with the above quote: The constructor is called with the (empty) braced-init-list.

Comment: +1 To clarify for OP, the code is equivalent in this case to `auto g = Foo(int{});`, and `int{} == 0`.

Comment: speaking of non-standard approaches, in `Visual Studio / msvc`, when the "list" contains 1 literal that can be interpreted as an integral type, e.g. `{42}`, that is not a list - as it should be according to the standard - but it's a "real" integer as far as the compiler - msvc - is concerned; example `auto a = {1}`, `a` it's an integer if you use `msvc` .

Comment: @user2485710: Are you sure that's nonstandard? While I wasn't paying careful attention, I do believe I've read `auto a = {1}` is *supposed* to deduce `int` as the type.

Comment: @Hurkyl the expected outcome in that particular case is an error because `{}` doesn't really has a type therefore according to the standard the compiler is supposed to see `auto` as a request for type deduction, `a` as a label, `=` as an assignment/copy ctor, `{1}` as something without a type with a literal in it; therefore the compiler shouldn't be able to deduce any type for `a` and that's why it's supposed to generate an error instead of an instance of an integral type . Microsoft added this exception to the rule and I don't think that this exception will make the use of `{}` better .

Comment: @user2485710 Initializer lists don't have a type because they're not expressions. But auto a = {1} is well-formed, and should not produce an error. The type should be deduced as std::initializer_list<int> (it's a much debated special case). If Microsoft deduces int, that's the bug. But you don't have to expect an error.

Comment: Post-[N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html), `auto a = {1};` should deduce a `std::initializer_list`, `auto a{1};` should deduce an `int`, and `auto a{1,2};` should be ill-formed.

Comment: @T.C. and `auto a{(1,2)}` will be an `int`.  :p

Comment: Note: A similar pitfall occurs with the assignment operator; `a = {};` will prefer `operator=(int)` over copy-assigning a temporary `Foo()`

Comment: So, if `({})` parameter list is interpreted as a list with a single argument, then the question shifts to the last initialization in the OP example: `Foo({2, 3})`. According to the OP, it calls the `Foo::Foo(int x, int y)` constructor. Why?

Comment: Oh, got it. Conceptually it is interpreted as `Foo(Foo{2 , 3})` meaning that *copy constructor* is the single-argument constructor that wins overload resolution in this case.

Comment: @AnT The move constructor, actually. You can observe that [with `-fno-elide-constructors`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc5e4a80a34de8ed).